# ItemTemplate DesignTime hints for custom control

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to create custom control with ItemsSource, which ItemTemplate for these items.

I have made it working, but one thing is left:

I would like to have DesignTime helper for binding within DataTemplate. Right now I can bind properties from Collection object, but there's no hints in XAML like with other bindings.

Of course I can do something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance models:User}">
        <Label Content="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <Label Content="{Binding LastName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

But I would like to avoid DesignTime instances entered manually.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: set the DataType property on the DataTemplate element

Answer (score 2):

```
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type User}>
```

By telling the DataTemplate the type that it represents; intellisense will give you DesignTime hints as to the properties available for Binding expressions

Comment: Yes, I know, but if you look at ListBox for example: there it's done in soma automatic way. Datatemplate know the type of Collection Item by default, so if you creating DataTemplate for ListBox, it automatically knows Properties of items.

Comment: Does your custom control extend ItemsControl?  ItemsControl defines ItemsSource and ItemTemplate and if you extend from that class, then intellisense should pick up the type of class you bind to ItemsSource in the same way that ListBox does.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But what if I would like to add 2nd ItemTemplate? For example ItemTemplate for ListBox and for TextBox inside my control? Adding ItemsControl as parent type is just a hack for handling that...

Comment: I suspect this logic is built into the XAML Designer - if you want a second item template I think defining the DataType will be the best way to handle your problem.  If you do not want users of your control to have to apply that data type in XAML, you could try and apply the datatype automatically from the setter callback of your dependency property in your custom control.  i.e. when someone sets the ItemsSource property, reflectively get the item type of the collection being bound and then set the datatemplate.datatype based on that type programmatically.